# Disable "apply instantly" option on every type of MDX Filter

Tags: filter, iccube-reporting

We are using large charts that take a lot of time to load after applying each filter individually. In order to minimize the user's waiting time we want to apply all filters only after the user presses an "apply all filters" button. Therefore we need to disable the "apply instantly" option for every filter. So far we are only able to do that with multiselect filters.

How can we do that with the other types of filters?

Answer (score 0):

Filters are different from a design point of view. How would you implement this 'do not apply instantly' on buttons and combos ?

Why not using a global filter if you have several filters on your widgets ?